# Can I use ZCatalogs Query Plan to Optimise Catalog Queries?

Tags: plone, zope

I'm wondering if I can make use of the information provided by the Query Report and Query Plan tabs on the portal catalog. Can I optimize ZCatalog queries based on the query report? How does ZCatalogs Query Plan differ from a query plan of an SQL database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query plan information is used to improve catalog performance, but you cannot optimize your own queries based on plan information.

The catalog only builds up that information as needed, based on your index sizes; unlike a SQL database the catalog does not plan each query based on such information but rather looks up pre-calculated plans from the structure reflected in the Query Plan tab.

The query report tab does give you information about what indexes are performing poorly for your code; you may want to rethink code that uses those combinations of indexes and/or look into why those indexes performed poorly; perhaps your query didn't limit the result quickly enough or the slow index is very large, indicating that perhaps your ZODB cache is too small to hold that large index or that other results keep pushing it out.

On the whole, for large applications it is a good idea to retain the query plan; in one project we dump cache information before stopping instances and reload that after starting again, and that includes the catalog query plan:

```
plan = site.portal_catalog.getCatalogPlan()
with open(PLAN_PATH, 'w') as out:
    out.write(plan)
```

and on load:

```
if os.path.exists(PLAN_PATH):
    from Products.ZCatalog.plan import PriorityMap
    try:
        PriorityMap.load_from_path(PLAN_PATH)
    except Exception:
        pass
```